# IntelliJ issues under Mac OS X using keyboard modifiers and clicking

Tags: macos, intellij-idea, keymapping

I'm on Mac OS X 10.11.6 and I cannot get `Navigate | Declaration/Type Declaration` working with command + left click. It seems that IntelliJ cannot see the modifier keys and clicking. I have tried both the powerbook trackpad and a Magic Mouse 2 and both give the same results. I've even tried setting up a new mouse shortcut as can be seen in this screenshot and I can confirm that the command key and clicking isn't getting picked up as seen in the screenshot:

[image]

Do I have something intercepting/interfering with modifier keys and clicking? This is a fresh install but I'm coming over from windows and so I'm out of my comfort level and running out of things to try.

**UPDATE**

Karabiner-Elements seemed to be interfering with modifiers and the mouse system wide. It was one of the first things I added after getting the computer in order to map caps lock to escape. Therefore, I completely forgot about it. I ended up hitting `Quit Karabiner-Elements` in the preferences menu for it and opening it back up to restart the daemon for the application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just tried doing this on:

```
IntelliJ IDEA 2016.2.4
Build #IU-162.2032.8, built on September 9, 2016
JRE: 1.8.0_112-release-b343 x86_64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
```

on OSX 10.10.5. I tried removing the <kbd>⌘</kbd> + `Button1 Click` and then adding it back and had no issue as seen below:

[image]

---

Since it works for me, it is unlikely to be a default OSX shortcut for OSX 10.10.5.  Regarding versions 10.11.x, the list of keyboard shortcuts is listed at https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT201236 which if filtered for the ones involving 'clicks' has :

```
Option–double-click     Open a folder in a separate window and close the current window.
Command–double-click    Open a folder in a separate tab or window.
Option-click a disclosure triangle  Open all folders within the selected folder. This works only when in list view.
Command-click a window title    See the folders that contain the current folder.
```

none of which should intercept the Command-click in Intellij.

Therefore it is likely to be another application consuming the `Command-click` that you are running. There are a couple of ways of confirming if this is the case. To figure out what the culprit application is does not seem to be straightforward and you might need to resort to trial and error.

---

#### Confirming *if* another application is intercepting Command-Click

Simpler way - Create another user

Follow the instructions here : https://support.apple.com/kb/PH18891?locale=en_US to create a new user. Out of the box, hopefully, this new user is cleaner and does not suffer from the same issue also proving that it is another application running for *your* user that is the problem.

The more interesting way - Karabiner's Event Viewer

Steps:

1. Install Karabiner from https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/
2. Open Karabiner -> Misc & Uninstall -> Event Viewer
3. Postion cursor over the *Mouse Area* and press <kbd>⌘</kbd> + `Button1 Click`
4. You should see something similar to this:

[image]

Here is the whole thing in action:
[image]

*If what you see does not match the above, you can be sure that another application is consuming <kbd>⌘</kbd> + `Left Button Click`.*

---

#### Finding out *which* application is intercepting Command-Click

One option to find out *which* application might be consuming keys is suggested here https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/104074/find-which-process-receives-a-given-keyboard-command and uses [`opensnoop`](http://osxdaily.com/2011/04/22/monitor-mac-os-x-filesystem-usage-access-with-opensnoop/) which works in the hopes that pressing a keystroke would cause the offending application to read some file on the filesystem. I tried using it but the output is a bit verbose so am uncertain of it's potential.